# Building selection query by looping through list

Tags: python, query, select-by-attribute

I would like to create a tool that selects census tracts based on input from a user. I have created an expression connecting values using "OR" but cannot figure out how to complete the expression without an "OR" tacked on at the end as well. Here is what I have:

```
inputTracts = input("Enter tract number(s): ")

# Create list from tract numbers
inputTracts = inputTracts.split(',')

# Declare string variable for list
inputExpression = ""

# Create expression from inputTracts
for i in inputTracts:
    if i != len(inputTracts):
        inputExpression = inputExpression + "tracts.GEOID10 =" + "'" + i + "'" + " OR "
    else:
        inputExpression + "tracts.GEOID10 =" + "'" + i + "'"
```

It ends up with something like

*tracts.GEO10 = 'XXX' OR tracts.GEO10 = 'YYY' OR*

which obliviously produces an error (due to the dangling "OR" at the end of the statement).

I was hoping the `if i != len(inputTracts)` and `else` statement would result in a different last value of the expression but I don't think I've done that correctly.

Is there a way to specify a different value for the last item in the list?

Comment: I see that I foolishly just used ```if i != len(inputTracts)``` when it obviously should have been the index of ```i```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Python question more than a Geospatial related one

```py
inputTracts = input("Enter tract number(s): ")

# Create list from tract numbers
inputTracts = inputTracts.split(',')

# Create a list of expression from inputTracts using comprehension list and f-string
list_of_statements = [f"tracts.GEOID10 = '{i}'" for i in inputTracts]
# Add the "OR" statement
inputExpression = ' OR '.join(list_of_statements)
```

Alternative using IN operator (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=expressions#operators) instead of OR

```py
list_of_statements = [f"'{i}'" for i in inputTracts]
inputExpression = f"tracts.GEOID10 IN ({','.join(list_of_statements)})"
```